# No buildable for testable

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, xcode-ui-testing

Trying to figure out first steps in UI testing with XCODE 7. My project has a pods component to it. For my actual project the record button is disabled, but if I create the test target in the Pods workspace/folder, then it is enabled. Catch being that if I click the record button it gives the message - "No buildable for testable". I'm using XCode 7Beta3. Any ideas if I'm missing any settings here.

One of the answers in another session was to delete and recreate the test target. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to delete/recreate the test target, click on your Xcode project file (the blueprint icon). It should then show you a sidebar that lists the Targets underneath the Project. Delete the *UITargets project, then recreate it by clicking on the + button. You can then add a new target by choosing "iOS UI Testing Bundle" under iOS -> Test.